# SQL Server Spaces within a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I need to add spaces within a string.

```
Original String: BM14401886
Expected Result: BM 14 4018 86
```

Comment: what are the conditions? should it always be 2-2-4-2?

Comment: @Nadeem_MK format is XX XX XXXX XX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can achieve this with `LEFT`, `SUBSTRING`, `RIGHT` functions.

### Query

```
SELECT LEFT('BM14401886',2)+' '+
SUBSTRING('BM14401886',3,2)+' '+
SUBSTRING('BM14401886',5,4)+' '+
RIGHT('BM14401886',2);
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1a2f3/1)

Answer (score 1):

I am completely agree with the @Ullas's answer.
But according to standard if we need to use space anywhare in the query then We shoul have to use

```
Space(no of space)
```

It is more readable after just seeing the query any one cant tell that how many space are used in the query.

Here case is simple but if you want to use 10 spaces in the query then it is not possible to say after seeing the query that how many spaces in the query.

```
SELECT LEFT('BM14401886',2)+space(1)+
SUBSTRING('BM14401886',3,2)+space(1)+
SUBSTRING('BM14401886',5,4)+space(1)+
RIGHT('BM14401886',2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this :

```
select substring(val,1,2) + ' ' + substring(val,3,2) + ' ' + 
substring(val,5,4) + ' ' + substring(val,9,2) as val
from yourtable
```

Sql fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e075f/3

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't really like the use of `LEFT`, `RIGHT` and `SUBSTRING` with things like this as it makes the SQL look messy.

If it's a one off with a single value in a stored procedure, you can do something like this:

```
declare @somestring as varchar(20) = 'BM14401886'
declare @position as int = 3 -- first space

while @position < LEN(@somestring)
begin
    select @somestring = stuff(@somestring, @position, 0, ' ')
    set @position = @position + 3
end

select @somestring as Result -- 'BM 14 40 18 86'
```

I'm assuming you might want to do this on a table column when you return multiple rows, in which case I would place this code inside a function that you can call.

```
create function AddSpacesToString (@somestring VARCHAR(20)) returns varchar(20)
as
begin
    declare @position as int = 3 -- first space

    while @position < LEN(@somestring)
    begin
        select @somestring = stuff(@somestring, @position, 0, ' ')
        set @position = @position + 3
    end   

    return @somestring
end
go
```

So your `SELECT` statement would look something like this without all the `LEFT`, `RIGHT` and `SUBSTRING`:

```
SELECT dbo.AddSpacesToString ([YourColumn]) as FormattedString
FROM [YourTable]
```